# How to refresh the enhanced grid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am using dojo 1.10 enhanced grid. Here after loading the grid we are using onStyleRow to highlight the grid row and cells but the problem is we only see highlighted a cell when we mouse hover the grid. Also, each time we update the new rows with color in store only.

My code is this -

```
function rowHighlighting()
{
    dojo.connect(mygrid, 'onStyleRow' , this, function(row){
        var item = mygrid.getItem(row.index);
        if(item){
            var store = mygrid.store;
            var type = store.getValue(item, 'ExceptionFixed',null);

            if(type == '1'){
                 row.customStyles += 'font-weight: bold !important;';

                 var cols = store.getValue(item, 'ExceptionFixedColumns',null);
                 cols = cols.split(",");

                 for(var i=0; i<cols.length;i++){

                     var nd = dojo.query('td[idx="' + i + '"]', row.node)[0];

                     if (cols[i] == "1" && _this.context.options.hideFixesVisibility.get("value") == 'Editable')
                         nd.style.color = "blue";
                     else
                         nd.style.color = "black";
                 }

             }
         }
    });
    //dijit.byId('grid').resize();
   // mygrid.render();
}
```

After this was not working I try to manually refresh the grid. By like this -

```
dijit.byId('grid').resize()
```

and this also

```
grid.render()
```

But it doesn't work. So, how can we manually do it as store is not reflecting?

Comment: you have registered for an onStyleRow event and un til focus is not on the row, your code won't get executed. try to use formatter to style our column.

Comment: I am unable to use formatter as I have asked regarding the same and also formatter will highlight whole column whereas I just want the cell.